# Word embedding - the meaning of rows and columns in embedded matrix

Tags: word2vec, word-embedding

I am learning word embedding. The resource that I went through was [link -Word embeddings](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings)

[image]

I am not able to understand the above image. I know, the values in each column represent the features of a word, rather than any specific word. This means the value 1.2 represent the feature cat, 0.4 represents represent the feature mat, 2.1 represent the features on. The vector `cat` has four rows, `mat` has four rows and `on` has four rows.

The heading of the picture is A 4-dimesional embedding. My doubt is why it is 4 dimensional? What is the meaning of dimension here?

Secondly, from where the values for cell (0,1) = -0.1 to cell(2,3) = 0.4 comes?

Thirdly, rows are represented by `cat`, `mat`, `on` but what is the meaning of the columns?

Another reference of embedding is [image] from [this link](https://medium.com/intelligentmachines/word-embedding-and-one-hot-encoding-ad17b4bbe111). Here they represent the column as `Man, Woman, King, Queen, Apple, Orange`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with python or tensorflow!

Answer (score 2):

1. 

In the embedding matrix, each row represents one word.
So "cat" is actually defined as a 4 dimensional vector `[1.2, -0.1, 4.3, 3.2]`, hence the 4-dimensional embedding title (The dimension of a vector is its length).

The idea is that by encoding words as high dimensional vectors, you can learn a high-dimensional space, where words which are related will be positioned closely together in this space. Also, how far along each axis in this high space a word is positioned tells us something about the meaning of the word. For example, a high value in column 2 might indicate that the word is feminine, whereas a low value indicates masculine.

2.

They are learnt values. You can look at the popular [word2vec](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word2vec) model to see one way of learning such embeddings.
Generally, they are based on a context learning approach. Where words which appear together in a sentence are probably related, so they will be placed close together in the high-dimensional representation we are learning. [Another relevant link](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2017-10-15-word-embedding/) for learning word embeddings

3.

The meaning of the columns is difficult to describe. The picture you link shows an example of what the values might mean. For example, column 1 (or row 1 in the image), might refer to gender, and its value indicates how related two words are within gender. In other words, if "man" has a value of 1, then "woman" will have a value of -1 since they are opposites.

Comment: To further emphasize your point #3: in typical dense learned embeddings like word2vec, each dimension typically does *not* have a neatly-interpretable meaning unless you take extra (uncommon, non-standard) steps to force that. So there may be vague 'neighborhoods' in the vector-space, or vague 'directions' (that aren't perfectly aligned with any axis/dimension, but rather shear across many/all dimensions), that have human-interpretable meanings. But those are usually found observationally, via comparisons/transformations of vectors – not definitively assigned/aligned to individual dimensions.